# Java : Component Z-order issue. Components go back to other components

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, awt, z-order

I have a JFrame and a JPanel on it. JPanel has a label that works as a picture. On that label I created buttons manually. It works fine when I set its z-order to 1. But when I delete that buttons and re-create, it just does not work and goes back of the label. They come front when I hover my mouse on them. Could anyone help me to solve this pls?

[image: This is at the begin when the program runs once]

[image: This is when I clicked change month button, and recreates the form]

```
panel.add(buttons[indexButtons],3); This is where I add the buttons manually. This one runs for multiple times after deleting older buttons each time when clicked change month button.

if(buttons[i]!=null)
        {
            //panel.setComponentZOrder(buttons[i], -1);
            panel.remove(buttons[i]);
            panel.repaint();

        }   This is how I remove oldest buttons.








label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(0, -11, 372, 309);
    panel.add(label); This is the background picture where I place buttons to
```

Answer (score 0):

> . JPanel has a label that works as a picture

So the label is now the background component (not the panel).

> But when I delete that buttons and re-create, it just does not work and goes back of the label

The buttons should be added to the JLabel NOT the JPanel so you have a component hierarchy like:

```
- JPanel
    - JLabel (with background image)
        - JButtons added to the label
```